# Linux Server Election - 1 of Many to Process Specific Jobs

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have a number of identical Linux servers that serve the same websites behind a load balancer.

I also have a number specific scheduled tasks that I need to run from only one Server like social networking posts, emailing out to users etc.

Rather then get a dedicated server to do this or modify the identical servers (so one is different) I wanted to keep all the same and have one do the processing.

I was therefore considering having a server election where all servers at a specific time on a cron schedule write to a table and the last one to do the update would be considered the one to do the processing.

```
update election_table set servername=?;
```

Is there a better way to do this? Interested to know how others would handle this situation and any better concepts.

Comment: If you want to do different jobs, but with identical servers why don't you use job queues?
Just put all the jobs into a queue and set up the servers to process these and that's all.

There are a lot of different queue implementations here: http://queues.io/
Choose one or try more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do different jobs, but with identical servers why don't you use job queues? Just put all the jobs into a queue and set up the servers to process these and that's all.  There are a lot of different queue implementations here: [queues.io](http://queues.io/) Choose one or try more.
                    – [Gerifield](/users/2504447/gerifield)